# html td tags not respecting width in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, css-position

I am having trouble creating a fixed-size table with no wrapping. I have tried looking in many places but cannot find a solution to this problem. I have posted codes of what I think seems to be the problem.

Here is the table ***layout*** I am trying to get:

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
 <th width="230px" rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">0
    </th>
    <td width="230px" colspan="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">8
 </td>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">9
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="41" style="border: 1px solid black;">14
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">15
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">16
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">17
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">18
 </td>
 <td>19
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Essentially, in the above table, boxes 0, 1, 8, 9 and 14 -- 18 are fixed width, and 19 is allowed to change size according to the other fixed widths. However, with this table, the entire table resizes with the window despite having `layout:fixed`. To combat that, I tried including `width="460px"`:

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:collapse;" width="460px">
<tr>
 <th width="230px" rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">0
    </th>
    <td width="230px" colspan="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">8
 </td>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">9
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="41" style="border: 1px solid black;">14
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">15
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">16
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">17
 </td>
 <td width="25" style="border: 1px solid black;">18
 </td>
 <td>19
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This does indeed solve the resizing problem, but now the desired widths for boxes 14 -- 19 are ignored! This has been extremely frustrating and I have tried many many suggestions from online.

A couple of my constraints:

- Trying to avoid divs since this is for an email signature and the
  mail clients I am trying to stay compatible with handle divs quite
  poorly
- I prefer not to use nested tables, since again, different mail
  clients seems to handle inline block / floating elements in quite
  different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" width="460px">
<tr>
 <th width="230px" rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">0
    </th>
    <td width="230px" colspan="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">8
 </td>
 <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">9
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="41px" style="border: 1px solid black;">14
 </td>
 <td width="25px" style="border: 1px solid black;">15
 </td>
 <td width="25px" style="border: 1px solid black;">16
 </td>
 <td width="25px" style="border: 1px solid black;">17
 </td>
 <td width="25px" style="border: 1px solid black;">18
 </td>
 <td width="auto">19
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, could you please explain why this works and what I was doing wrong? i.e. why is `table-layout:fixed` not required?

Answer (score 0):

Try, style="max-width: 41px" maybe works.

Comment: No luck. Adding "max-width:41px" to box 14 is still ignored after the addition of "460px" on the full table. Also tried "min-width:41px", but no luck there either.